# Generate an array of source lines from a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to obtain an array of lines from a JavaScript function. Given a reference to a specific function, I would like to return an array where each element consists of a single consecutive line of the function's source.

#### Example:

```
//the following function will be used as the input for getArrayOfLines, and each line of  functionToUse should be returned as output (represented as a string).
function functionToUse(){
    //This comment here should be included in the array of lines.
    //This is the second line that should be in the array.
}

var funcLines = getArrayOfLines(functionToUse);

// should return: 
// [ "//This comment here should be included in the array of lines.", 
//   "//This is the second line that should be in the array." ]
```

Here's where I'm at:

```
function getArrayOfLines(theFunction){
    //return an array of lines from the function that is entered as input.
    //each line should be represented as a string
    var theString = theFunction.toString();
    // now I'll need to generate an array of lines from the string, 
    // and then return the array
}
```

Mainly, I'm trying to do this so that I can evaluate each line of a function (one line at a time).

Comment: I still don't know why this question was downvoted. :/

Answer (score 0):

Simple - all you need to do is use `stringtoSplit.split("\n")` to obtain an array of lines.

Demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FDCh6/2/

```
function getArrayOfLines(theFunction){
    var theString = theFunction.toString();
    //now I'll need to generate an array of lines from the string, and then return the array
    var arrToReturn = theString.split("\n");
    return arrToReturn.slice(1, arrToReturn.length-1);
}

function functionToUse(){
    //This comment here should be included in the array of lines.
    //This is the second line that should be in the array.
}

alert(getArrayOfLines(functionToUse)); //get the array of lines from functionToUse
```

Comment: StackOverflow has become a Pop Quiz :P

Comment: @Oded Yes, I didn't think the answer to this question was obvious at first. Is "self-answering" questions considered unconstructive for some reason? And which of my questions are considered problematic?

Comment: Self-answering is fine. Just make sure your question is as clear as possible (often a bit tricky after you've already solved it!) so that others can find it and benefit

Comment: why are you passing in a function? each function has hardcoded lines and you pass functions instead of strings!?

Comment: @Nick: there are a few different reasons to do something like this. Anderson sounds like he's writing a simple debugger, but I've seen and used similar setups to generate code at runtime based on "template" functions, and (in the context of userscripts) to insert code into the context of a web page without having to stuff it into strings while writing it.

Comment: @NickCardoso Instead of simply splitting a string into an array, the function is intended to obtain an array of lines from a function's source code (as explained in the original question).

Comment: So this isn't quite right: since toString() will return the entire function definition, the example will return an array with four elements: the first being `"function functionToUse(){"` and the last `"}"`.

Comment: @Shog9 In that case, would it be considered correct if the first and the last elements of the array were removed?

Comment: For the example, yes. If I wrote a function that put the opening brace on a new line, it'd be wrong again... Whether that matters really depends on the source of the input and what you're doing with the output; since JS is (mostly) whitespace-agnostic, you could write a function that would break anything that wasn't actually able to do a bit of rough syntax-parsing.

Comment: @Shog9 I've fixed this problem now: only the lines inside the function are returned now.